# PHP Password Session Variable Encryption

Tags: php, session, encryption, authentication, passwords

I have a typical username/password login system where the username enters their credentials however the authorization is determined by the SQL Server connection rather than using a query to check a table of usernames and passwords.

> ```
> $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db); 
> $oLink = sqlsrv_connect($Server,$connectionInfo);
> ```

I already have it all set up working as intended with session variables to hold username and password (which I don't feel safe about). Is there a way to add encryption to the password session variable and implement a way to have it function with my authorization setup?

> ```
> $usr = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
> $pwd = $_SESSION['PASSWORD'];
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd worry more about [Session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) and then concentrate on using a secure password storage/retrieval system. You shouldn't be using such a method.

Comment: 1) Why are you storing the password in the session? 2) Why do you think that's unsafe?

Comment: I have multiple pages that connect to different databases. Some databases only allow certain users to access it so each page that connects to these database use a different $db variable to do the authentication. I guess this is what I have to deal with as I use server connection for authentication as opposed to a db table checkup with usernames/passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using your method, try using md5 or sha256.

For example : $newpassword= md5($pwd); 
The $newpassword will be encrypted.

But note that the stored password should also be encrypted, so that if the two encryptions match, then the passwords match.

PS : md5 is no longer a trusted encryption method so try to use sha256 or higher.

Comment: But if I'm encrypting $pwd and use the new encrytped $newpassword to connect to the database, the encrypted string will be input into:
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);    $oLink = sqlsrv_connect($Server,$connectionInfo);

Comment: you could use an ecryption decryption method like the one here http://runnable.com/UmmNdePavBUxAABZ/php-mcrypt-basic-encryption-and-decryption-of-a-string

ecrypt the password in the session and then decrypt it before using it in the connectioninfo

Comment: Wow. This is very neat stuff. Thank you!